# how can i add list of items in single column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I wanted to create table.
for example,

```
create table countryrules(cname varchar(15), rule1, rule2);
```

here, `rule1` and `rule2` contain list of strings. 
so, please suggest me which datatype i can use?

Comment: list of strings?? Can you be more specific

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Never, never, never store multiple values in one column!

Instead use another table to relate countries and rules.

```
country table
-------------
id
name
other_column


rule table
----------
id
name
other_column


countryrules table
------------------
country_id
rule_id
```

Comment: any reason why we shouldn't store multiple values in one column ?

Comment: @Gagantous: The most important reasons are: It is hard to query and slow in performance.

Answer (score 1):

`strings` in a table column.....!!

Mate, this is a `database`, it should contain specific values, if you plan to store `string` in your schema, i suggest you `normalize` your entire database plan from a scratch and then come up with schema to store values in more efficient way!!!!! :)

**juergen d**'s schema is good one to start with!! :D

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are trying to define a constrained list of values for a column.
If it is true then you can try with `enum` or `set` of values.

***Example***:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `set_of_values` (
    ->   `e` enum('yes','no') DEFAULT 'no',
    ->   `s` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `e2` enum('ok','ok_2','not_ok') DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `e3` enum('ok','ok_2','not_ok') NOT NULL,
    ->   `st` set('a','b','c') DEFAULT 'c'
    -> )
    -> ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.45 sec)

mysql>
mysql> desc set_of_values;
+-------+----------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type                       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+----------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| e     | enum('yes','no')           | YES  |     | no      |       |
| s     | varchar(10)                | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| e2    | enum('ok','ok_2','not_ok') | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| e3    | enum('ok','ok_2','not_ok') | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| st    | set('a','b','c')           | YES  |     | c       |       |
+-------+----------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```